# Why does sizeof operator on an array give incorrect result?

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   ostringstream outStr;

   const char* strArray[]= {"Hi","How" ,"Howhuw","bdeuvc"};
   int n;
   cout << sizeof(strArray);
}
```

Why am I getting the output 32? Can someone please explain this to me? I know I'm having an array of 4 elements here but how is it's size 32?

Comment: Hi, sizeof() returns the size allotted not the length of the the array. Each character is a size of 8 bits. so 4 elements in the array so it returns 32. If you want to calculate the no of elements. Do ```sizeof(strArray)/8```

Comment: The `sizeof` operator returns the size in *bytes*. To get the number of elements use `sizeof strArray / sizeof strArray[0]`.

Comment: fwiw, `std::vector<std::string>` is for beginners, c-arrays are compilcated and error-prone (with not much benefit in most situations)

Comment: @Aravind Yes I know but size of char is just 1 So it should be 4 that way

Comment: @AshRay Yah its 1byte = 8 bits and it shows in bits

Comment: @AshRay Can you provide a better tittle than "Can anybody explain me . I am a beginner in C++"

Comment: `sizeof(strArray)` is `4 * sizeof (const char*)` (4 as you array contains 4 elements)

Comment: @Aravind So when I use sizeof(char) then why it shows 1 instead of 8 ????

Comment: A `char` is one byte. A `char*` depends on the size of pointers but likely 8 bytes if your program is 64 bit or 4 bytes if your program is 32.

Comment: @AshRay It returns the value in bits not in bytes

Comment: @AshRay its bytes not bits I am not sure why people are giving you wrong advice.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: @drescherjm Yes thank you It returns in bytes I am also not sure why there are different answers.

Comment: The documentation link from @Jarod42 should clear up any confusion.

Comment: Use `std::size(strArray)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sizeof returns the size in bytes.

```c++
char x = 'a';
cout << sizeof(x); // this would be 1
```

This means that the space taken by the array of characters is their count * 1 byte

`int` on most modern machines is 32 bit (4 bytes)

If you had, let's say `int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }`
and you wanted to get the count of its elements you might do the following:

```c++
cout << sizeof(array)/sizeof(int); // (20 / 4) -> 5
```

EDIT:

What you've declared here:

```c++
const char* strArray[]= {"Hi","How" ,"Howhuw","bdeuvc"};
```

It's an array that contains 4 `char*` (char pointers). The size of char pointer on your machine is 8 bytes.

```c++
char* x = "a";
cout << sizeof(x);
```

A pointer is a variable (you can think of it as an integer) that holds the adress in memory where the variable it's pointing at starts:

strArray[0] points at a memorry adress where "Hi" starts.
strArray[1] points at a memorry adress where "How" starts.
... and so on

Comment: No problem!
You can mark it as the best answer, so that other poeople will be able to easily find it ;)

Comment: Note that there is no need to use that `sizeof` incantation. There is a template function in the standard for this purpose: `std::size`.

Comment: Of course, I just just gave an example usage of sizeof

Comment: It seems like this answer is not directly related to question. OP has array of `char*`, not ints.

Comment: I've just updated it

Answer (score -1):

Each array of characters placed inside `" "` in the character array consumes `8 bytes` that's why you're getting output as `32 bytes` if you add one more string in it it will show `40 bytes`.

Comment: sizeof() returns in bytes or bits. Another answer says it returns in bytes ???

Comment: I think you mean *bytes* not bits?

Comment: @AshRay: `sizeof` returns in bytes: `sizeof(char)==1`, `sizeof(const char*)==8` in your platform (might be different number for other config).

Comment: yes @AshRayand  it's bytes. Sorry my bad.

Comment: yes @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: There are no strings in the array.

Comment: Now is it okay? @SergeyA